# Android Paging 3: Merge items based on attributes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3

I'm facing an issue while implementing paging 3 library in Android. Below is an example of the items I'm getting in 2 pages. It shows 3 items as below:
1st Item: Movie A, with actors : 1,2,3
2nd Item: Movie A, with actors : 4,5,6
3rd Item: Movie B, with actors : 4,5,6

Expected output is:
1st Item: Movie A, with actors : 1,2,3,4,5,6
2nd Item: Movie B, with actors : 4,5,6

I want to merge actors based on the movie id. Any suggestion would be appritiated.

> Page 1

```
{
  "data": {
    "movies": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "A",
        "actors": [
          "1",
          "2",
          "3"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "Success",
  "status": 200
}
```

> Page 2

```
{
  "data": {
    "movies": [
      {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "A",
        "actors": [
          "4",
          "5",
          "6"
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "345",
        "name": "B",
        "actors": [
          "4",
          "5",
          "6"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "message": "Success",
  "status": 200
}
```

> Movie.kt

```
data class Movie(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val actors: List<String>
)
```

> MovieDataSource.kt

```
class MovieDataSource : PagingSource<Int, Movie>() {
    private val mergedMoviesMap = HashMap<String, Movie>()

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Movie> {
        return try {
            // Fetch data from your API using the "params.key" as a page number
            val pageDataResponse = /* Fetch data for page params.key */
            val movies = pageDataResponse.data.movies ?: listOf()
           
            // Return the data and prev/next keys for pagination
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = movies,
                prevKey = if (params.key > 1) params.key - 1 else null,
                nextKey = if (movies.isNotEmpty()) nextPageNumber else null
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle any errors that may occur during data fetching
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

> MovieAdapter.kt

```
class MovieAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<Movie, MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder>(MovieDiffCallback()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_movie, parent, false)
        return MovieViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(movie)
    }

    class MovieViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val nameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView)
        private val actorsTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.actorsTextView)

        fun bind(movie: Movie?) {
            movie?.let {
                nameTextView.text = it.name
                actorsTextView.text = it.actors.joinToString(", ")
            }
        }
    }

    class MovieDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Movie>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```